# Django Model.objects.get(...) case-insensitivity

Tags: django, database, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am developing a dictionary application and I have an `Expression` model defined as follows:

```
class Expression(models.Model):
    expression = models.CharField()
```

In one of my views, I am using `Expression.objects.get_or_create(expression=expression)`.

**Importantly, I want the comparison between "expression" and all existing `Expression` objects in my database to be case-insensitive.**

In other words, even though this is not valid syntax, I would like the logic of my search to be: `Expression.objects.get_or_create(expression.lower()=expression.lower())`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Even if `x.lower() == y.lower()` was possible, this is *not* case-insensitive checking. There are more sophisticated rules. For example some characters do not *have* a lowercase variant. This is why `.casefold()` was designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do case-insensitive filter as below:

```
Expression.objects.get_or_create(expression__iexact=expression.lower())
```

Look at [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) for other field lookups.

**Note:**  `get_or_create` method can create duplicate items in database because of race condition. Be sure that you pass **unique** field or fields that are **unique together** to this method for avoiding possible duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Could you please point me to some documentation regarding what you just said about race conditions? Thank you.

Comment: Also, should I pass a defaults argument to get_or_create when I use __iexact? Thanks

Comment: @fredperk i am not sure there is a note about get_or_create race condition in django documentation. I've seen such case in my experience.